# How do I use jquery-ui checkbox within widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using a jquery-ui checkbox within a container that has class ui-widget-content on it.  This is causing the ".ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover" css rule that defines the background property to override the .ui-icon-check rule that defines the correct background-position for the checkbox image. I believe this is because it is more specific.

The result is that a checkbox within a widget shows the wrong image.  How should I handle this?

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/8ez1qcmL/).  In the second div where I have the ui-widget-content class, you can see the checked image is wrong.

```
<div class="ui-widget-content">
<label for="cb3">Test 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" class="toggle"/>
<label for="cb4">Test 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb4" class="toggle" checked="checked"/>
</div>
```

Note that I can't change the parent div.  I am working within a dialog that requires that class.

I am surprised I can't find anybody else complaining about this.  I am not sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

So the `.ui-icon-check` class is being overwritten by a later style. You can just write it back.

One Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ewabcy3g/2/
(Fixed for blank)

**CSS**

```
.ui-widget-content label span.ui-icon-check {
  background-position: -64px -144px;
}
.ui-widget-content label span.ui-icon-blank {
  background-position: 16px 16px;
}
```

Another Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ewabcy3g/1/

**jQuery**

```
$('.nonwidget,.ui-widget-content').controlgroup({
  "direction": "vertical"
}).find(".ui-icon-check").css("background-position", "-64px -144px");
```

Hope that helps.

**Update**

Found something interesting, still a bit of a hack but it seems to help:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ewabcy3g/3/

When I removed the checked attribute and set it via jQuery, like so:

```
$('.toggle').checkboxradio();
$("#cb4").attr("checked", true);
$('.nonwidget,.ui-widget-content').controlgroup({
  "direction": "vertical"
});
```

I could remove the CSS hacks. I found that setting the CSS positioning back, it was still reading the hover background image and not retaining the proper styling.

I then tried adding `checked="checked"` back to the HTML and it got screwed up again.

Comment: It helps a little, I guess.  It seems like a total hack for a jquery-ui bug.  Your examples don't fully work, either, because when you uncheck the box, it is messed up again.  So I'd have to redefine at least ui-icon-check and ui-icon-blank.

Comment: @Backslider the second example works better. I see what you're saying regarding the first example. What I see happening is that `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover` class is resetting the value to `50%, 50%`.

Comment: I actually am setting the checked property through code.  I think the difference is that I was setting it before calling checkboxradio().  If I move it to after, that causes it not to put the hover class on, I think, which makes the styles stay in the right order.